# Outputting PHP within a HTML tag in PHP

Tags: php, html

Kind of stuck on this one issue, tried all the ways of outputting regular HTML in PHP which works fine, but when trying get PHP code and then making that into HTML link where everything is in PHP. Line 17 & 18 is the issue, this maybe very simple to someone, but its proven difficult for me :( 
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
  <?php  

    if($output == true) { 

                echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$fname."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$lname."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$dob."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$gender."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$hnumber."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$mnumber."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$email."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$username."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$address."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$type."</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='memberdelete.php?id=".$rows['ID']."'>Delete</a></td>";                   echo "<td><a href='memberedit.php?id=".$rows['ID']."'>Edit</a></td>";        
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: If quotes trouble you, you might want to look into using [`HEREDOC`](http://php.net/heredoc) syntax. Or a template engine.

Comment: Cheers for that! The fix by Rikesh works nicely!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change it to,

```
echo "<td><a href='memberdelete.php?id=".$rows['ID']."'>Delete</a></td>";
```

**Useful:** [How strings work in PHP ?](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I wrote it quickly, hope it work:

```
echo '<td><a href="memberdelete.php?id='.$rows['ID'].'">Delete</a></td>';
echo '<td><a href="memberedit.php?id='.$rows['ID'].'">Edit</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Horrible enclosing of quotes and multiple echo on same line was your problem.

Update to:

```
 echo "<td><a href='memberdelete.php?id=".$rows['ID']."'>Delete</a></td>";
 echo "<td><a href='memberedit.php?id=".$rows['ID']."'>Edit</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for the above code:

```
 <?php  

    if($output == true) { 

                echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$fname."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$lname."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$dob."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$gender."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$hnumber."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$mnumber."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$email."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$username."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$address."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$type."</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='memberdelete.php?id=".$rows['ID']."'>Delete</a></td>";
                echo "<td><a href='memberedit.php?id=".$rows['ID']."'>Edit</a></td>";

            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced the quotes and html tags.so

change

```
echo "<td>".<a href="memberdelete.php<?php echo '?id='.$rows['ID']; ?>">Delete</a>."</td>";
echo "<td>".<a href="memberedit.php<?php echo '?id='.$rows['ID']; ?>"
```

to

```
 echo "<td><a href='memberdelete.php?id=$rows[ID]'>Delete</a></td>";
 echo "<td><a href='memberedit.php'?id='$rows[ID]'>Edit</a></td>";
```

If you have problem with quotes and assigning values to parameters inside quotes try [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect strings.
changes those lines:

```
 echo "<td>".<a href="memberdelete.php<?php echo '?id='.$rows['ID'];?>">Delete</a>."</td>";
 echo "<td>".<a href="memberedit.php<?php echo '?id='.$rows['ID']; ?>"
```

to:

```
 echo "<td><a href=\"memberdelete.php<?php echo '?id='.$rows['ID']; ?>\">Delete</a></td>";
 echo "<td><a href=\"memberedit.php<?php echo '?id='.$rows['ID']; ?> </td>"
```